# How the data stored on Cloud?

Tags: cloud, datastore

I am novice to Cloud Computing. Is it a server ? Is the data stored on the Cloud move from server per to server ? or Actually what does it mean by storing data on Cloud ?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud_storage

Comment: Aren't marketing terms like this generally as close to meaningless as you get? I'm so tired of calling that thing we used to call the "Internet", the "Cloud" instead.

Comment: Now, now Cody.  The Cloud is much more than just the Internet.  Why, according to Microsoft, the Cloud does everything.  You don't need software any more to do things.  You just say, "To The Cloud", and all your problems are solved.  :-)

Comment: @Gilbert: Haha yeah, so I've heard. I guess the bright side is that Microsoft learned from their original mistakes, and is now embracing "The Cloud" much faster than they originally moved to embrace "The Internet".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The cloud is a term for a group of servers offering a service. So if your hosting(storing) your data in the cloud it means you have signed up for a service that allows you to remotely store and retrieve your data.

The data will be stored on a physical server some where but the benefit of the cloud is you don't have to worry about the how and maintaining the hardware/software. Though you do have to trust your data to someone else.

here is a good article on it http://www.pcworld.com/businesscenter/article/164933/cloud_computing_explained.html

Answer (score 0):

Basically it means that your data is accessible from internet and is reliably stored.

Answer (score 0):

The name Cloud comes from the fact that the symbol for the Internet in network diagrams usually is a cloud.

Now that beeing said storing data in the Cloud doesn't mean anything except that it's stored somewhere on one or multiple server's harddrives in a datacenter somewhere around the world. Depending on the service you choose to use of cause.

What Cloud services change are just two things. First of all they make it possible for everyone to access their stored data from anywhere through common web technologies. In the past services like this were often only possible for large corporations with custom setups and huge costs. Second they offer these services in a variety of package sizes fitting for everything from personal use to small and medium sized businesses and even enterprises.

Answer (score 0):

Storing a data on the "Cloud" refers to the remote storage of data. Often this involves internet based services (such as Dropbox, SugarSync etc..).

Basically, these services run data centres that deploy a middleware which enables these services to pool the storage resources from commodity servers. Therefore, they have tons of storage space which they can use to sell over the internet.

Answer (score 0):

To understand this, it is essential to know the basics of cloud. A cloud is basically a cluster of multiple dedicated servers attached within a network. The architecture is such that the entire resources such as CPU, RAM, storage etc. are combined together that forms a large pool. When an application/website is hosted in a cloud infrastructure, it means the resources would be served from this pool.

Now, unlike the traditional hosting types where if the server hardware fails for some reason, your application or websites tend to go unresponsive causing a downtime, but in cloud, despite one of the servers within the cluster going down, your application/website wouldn't face any downtime, which is one of the most essential requirements of todays highly competitive industry. You can access your data from anywhere provided you have access to the Internet. ;)